# Getting FlatList item's position's coordinates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a FlatList, and I'm trying to get each item's `x, y, width, height` to do some animations. I've seen it's possible with `.measure` and maybe even `useRef`, but I'm not sure how to do it within FlatList's `renderItem` since I can't use hooks within it.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const renderItem = React.useCallback(
    ({ item, index }) => {
      const coords = // ! How can I get these?
      
      return (
        <View key={item.id} style={containerStyle}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.uri }}
              style={memoizedStyles.media}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
      <FlatList
        data={myData}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if a scrollable FlatList adds complexity here. Maybe it's best to measure `onPress` or something? Regardless, some help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that you can't use hooks directly in the `renderItem` callback there, but you can create your own wrapper component and call that instead:

```
const Item = ({ item }) =>
  {
    return (
      <View key={item.id} style={containerStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: item.uri }}
            style={memoizedStyles.media}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  ...

    const renderItem = React.useCallback(({ item, index }) => <Item item={item} />);
  ...
```

So far as getting the item size is concerned, you can certainly do this using `useRef` and `ref.measure(...)` but [as the React Native docs note](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback), you can get results sooner and slightly more easily [using the `onLayout` prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout).

```
const Item = ({ item }) =>
  {
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState();
    return (
      <View key={item.id} style={containerStyle}
        onLayout={ e => setCoords(e.nativeEvent.layout) }>
          ...
```

`coords` will initially be undefined, but as soon as each `Item` renders/re-renders `coords` will contain `{x,y,left,top,width,height}`.

**EDIT 1**

So – the `x` and `y` values are relative to each item's View container and not super useful for you, sorry!

Looks like react-native-web also provides `left` and `top` values in the `LayoutEvent` that are not available on other platforms. So, we should use `.measure(..)` instead:

```js
const Item = ({ item }) =>
  {
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState();
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() =>
      ref.current.measure(
        (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) =>
           setCoords({ width, height, pageX, pageY })
      ),
      [ref,setCoords]);

    return (
      <View key={item.id} style={containerStyle} ref={ref}>
        ...
```

This gives `pageX`/`pageY` – the absolute coordinates on the page.
There's also the [`measureLayout()` function](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurelayoutrelativetonativecomponentref-onsuccess-onfail) which can give you coordinates relative to another component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem I'm seeing is that all of the View's rendered in the flatList end up with the same coords: `{"height": 180, "width": 115, "x": 246, "y": 8}`. I tried console.loggging the coords when each item is clicked, and they're all the same

Comment: @nalabof679 Sorry about that – the `left` and `top` properties have the relevant coordinates for you but if they're not available on your platform then it's not so useful :-)